# Is it okay to use brass inserts in a plastic reverse osmosis pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water, safety

I've learned that letting metal contact reverse osmosis filtered water is generally a bad idea as it corrodes the metals and leaches them into the clean water supply.

However, I'm having a hard time finding a fully plastic 1/4-in compression fitting (1/4-in female to 1/4-in male) to connect my RO line to my refrigerator.  Should I be concerned about the copper insert that will be in contact with the RO-filtered water?  Will it affect the integrity of the connection and/or the water quality?

Comment: Ha, thanks Ecnerwal.  I usually change a few unimportant words when editing something like that.  I certainly want to keep leeches out of the fresh water supply though.  Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here are some that appear to be fully-plastic, and/or plastic + stainless steel](http://www.usplastic.com/catalog/default.aspx?catid=606&parentcatid=855)

Without knowing what particular fitting you need (1/4 compression to what?), hard to get more specific than that. Full plastic fittings are out there, and really are what you want, as RO & DI water do love to eat anything that will  give them ions. My reading on the above fittings is that the stainless (which is as good a choice as you get in metal, though aluminum may also work well from what I recall of an old lab D.I.W. system) is not in the normally wetted path.

[Here is another supplier's nylon/polypro fittings:](http://hosewarehouse.com/Field-Specific-Eaton-Brass/Field-Specific-Eaton-Brass-Eaton-Molded-Compression-Tube-Fittings)

Comment: Yup those are the fittings used, I think I seen them in local local hardware store also. I won't mention the names but the national chain stores should carry them. Incredibly easy to install, nice even, square cut on the pipe, push it on fully, done.

Comment: I did find one at Lowe's after writing this, but the threaded end of the compression fitting was oddly the wrong size once I got home.  The package had been unopened but was clearly marked 1/4-in.  I think the threaded end was actually 3/8 or 1/2.  Incidentally, I think I'm going to cut the plastic hose on my fridge and just get a push-fit union because I think they probably already used metal ferrules inside the compression fitting attached to the fridge hose at the factory.